# Does anyone knows why my password doesn't work? Eclipse & Github

Tags: eclipse, github, passwords

I'm trying to push a branch from Eclipse to a repository in Github, but at the moment of logging in i just can't. Although, I can access to my account in my browser.
I assume i have to use my username and my password from github (I've had also tried with my eclipse account tho). I have changed my password already, just because i thought i was writing it wrong.
I am thinking on just deleting my account at the moment. Please, help. [Maybe i'm doing something wrong?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aJVv5.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if this is exactly what's causing your issue, but GitHub
[recently phased out the use of passwords for authenticating git operations](https://github.blog/2020-12-15-token-authentication-requirements-for-git-operations/).

Instead you'll have to use something else, like a [Personal Access Token](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/creating-a-personal-access-token), which, as far as I remember, you enter in just like a password.